# Installing Python plus ArcMap plus ArcGIS Pro plus GDAL?

Tags: python, gdal, installation, arcgis-pro, arcgis-10.5

My various installations of ArcMap, OSGeo4W and Python 2.7 (plus 3.4) are a mess. I've resorted to copying the entire Gdal directory (per version and processor) to the site-packages directory of all the Python installations (and things generally work) but this seems wrong. So I'm asking anyone with experience to help me out with a good installation. Here's what I've done:

1. Installed Python 2.7 (64-bit) to C:\Python
2. Installed Python 2.7 (32-bit) to C:\Pythonx86
3. Installed ArcMap 10.5 without Python
4. Installed ArcMap's Background Processing which automatically installs Python 2.7 into the ArcGISx64 directory
5. Installed OSGeo4W64 to C:\Program Files
6. Installed OSGeo4W to C:\Program Files (x86)
7. Installed ArcGIS Pro 1.4 which automatically installs Python 3.4

The biggest problem, of course, is that Python (and all the mods) gets deleted whenever I'm forced to reinstall ArcGIS (which happens way too often, unfortunately). Another problem is that sometimes Gdal returns an error when I import it in a script. Another problem is that the IDLE shell almost randomly switches between 32- and 64-bit versions even when clicking on the same shortcut.

Well, basically what I want is detailed help with the proper installation of these programs (and no, I don't want to switch to QGIS :))

Comment: At which step did things first start not to work as you expected?

Comment: You can only use one of these Python installs at a time, so it's not obvious what your problem might be. I'd skip 1 and 2, and let Desktop install the first Python.

Comment: I'm having the same problem but I'm worried about modifying the system variables path too much in case it stuffs up ArcPro.  I've started using Virtual machines, Oracle Virtual Box to separate them all out.

Comment: Well, according to many people (via Googling), it's completely possible to have multiple installations of Python on the same computer. In fact, just installing ArcGIS Desktop and ArcGIS Pro will install three different Python versions. My problem is getting everything to work with GDAL. I think the main problem is the order of installation plus the environmental settings.